# Login Authentication fail

Tags: android, ksoap2

i am use ksoap web service for user login .. but when i am add username and password then get message login fail...how can i solve it.. username = adc and password = adc is already strore in web service

MainActivity.class

```
public class DotNetWSActivity extends Activity {
static boolean errored = false;
Button b;
TextView tv;
EditText et ,pw;
boolean loginStatus;
ProgressBar pg;
String UserName ,Password;
String LoginAuthentication;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Name Text control
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    //Display Text control
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    //Button to trigger web service invocation
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //Display progress bar until web service invocation completes
    pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    //Button Click Listener
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Check if Name text control is not empty
            if (et.getText().length() != 0 && et.getText().toString() != "") {
                 if (pw.getText().length() != 0 && pw.getText().toString() != "") {
                //Get the text control value
                UserName = et.getText().toString();
                Password =pw.getText().toString();
                //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                //Call execute 
                task.execute();
            //If text control is empty
            } else {
                tv.setText("Please enter name");
            }
            }else {
                  tv.setText("Please enter password");
            }
        }
    });
}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        LoginAuthentication = WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(UserName, Password,"LoginAuthentication");
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
//      webservicePG.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Intent intObj = new Intent(DotNetWSActivity.this,dfdf.class);
        //Error status is false
        if(!errored){
            //Based on Boolean value returned from WebService
            if(loginStatus){
                //Navigate to Home Screen
                startActivity(intObj);
            }else{
                //Set Error message
                tv.setText("Login Failed, try again");
            }
        //Error status is true   
        }else{
            tv.setText("Error occured in invoking webservice");
        }
        //Re-initialize Error Status to False
        errored = false;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

}

}
```

this is my Webservice class

```
public class WebService {

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String URL ="http://192.168.0.100/xandroid.asmx";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";


public static String invokeHelloWorldWS(String UserName,String Password, String webMethName) {
    String resTxt = null;
     boolean loginStatus = false;
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
    // Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo celsiusPI = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set Name
    celsiusPI.setName("UserName");
    // Set Value
    celsiusPI.setValue(UserName);
    celsiusPI.setName("Password");
    // Set Value
    celsiusPI.setValue(Password);
    // Set dataType
    celsiusPI.setType(String.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(celsiusPI);
    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        // Invole web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to fahren static variable
          loginStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());
//      resTxt = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        resTxt = "Error occured";
    } 

    return resTxt;
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
07-24 12:13:47.121: W/System.err(1593): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 12:13:47.121: W/System.err(1593):     at   com.prgguru.android.WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(WebService.java:50)
07-24 12:13:47.141: W/System.err(1593):     at com.prgguru.android.DotNetWSActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(DotNetWSActivity.java:63)
07-24 12:13:47.151: W/System.err(1593):     at com.prgguru.android.DotNetWSActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(DotNetWSActivity.java:1)
07-24 12:13:47.151: W/System.err(1593):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-24 12:13:47.151: W/System.err(1593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-24 12:13:47.151: W/System.err(1593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-24 12:13:47.151: W/System.err(1593):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
07-24 12:13:47.151: W/System.err(1593):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-24 12:13:47.162: W/System.err(1593):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-24 12:13:47.162: W/System.err(1593):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Which line is WebService.java:50?

Comment: in webservice class , have u get the username and password values? check first.

Comment: yes i got value in webservice class

Comment: @Jens means i dont understand??

Comment: @user3871733 You get a NPE in line 50 of your class. What i have to know is what is line 50 in class Webservice?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things

In your doInBackground

```
LoginAuthentication = WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(UserName, Password,"LoginAuthentication");
```

You're calling a method from a class that has not been instantiated. What I would recommend is create a constructor inside WebService and takes those 3 parameters, then have a getter in the class to return `resTxt`. Then your call to the class would look like

```
WebService webservice = new WebService(UserName, Password,"LoginAuthentication");
String  LoginAuthentication = webservice.getResTxt();
```

Or if you insist on keeping the format you have right now, you still have to instantiate the class by calling `new WebService` first.

The only reason you're not getting a compiling error right now is because your `invokeHelloWorldWS` method is static... which from what I can, there is no reason that it should be static.

Also, you're passing in NULL from doInBackground to onPostExecute... why? The point on onPostExecute is to take the value from doInBackground and do something with it.